# Can I realize Chacha20/Poly1305 in openSSL CLI?

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography

Let's say I would like to realize Chacha20/Poly1305 encryption/decryption in openSSL CLI - is it possible?

The setup:
Input: payload with passphrase and nonce.

1. passphrase length is 32 bytes
2. nonce is 12 bytes
3. payload to be encrypted

Output:

1. Ciphertext with a 16-byte crypto-tag appended.